# Is it possible to skip the "execute statements" wait in a For loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I am using a for loop to give selenium URLs from a list, though i do not want to wait for every page to load for the next site to be loaded on a separate browser. Is there a way to skip the wait in the execute statements step of a For loop ?

```py
def getUrl(x):
     driver.get(x)


for x in URLS:
     getUrl(x)
```

I would like all of the sites to be loaded at the same time.

Comment: Your code does not open each url in separate browser, it will open in the same browser. Are you trying to open bunch of urls in different tabs/windows?

Comment: Yes thats what i am trying to do exactly. But i dont wanna wait for the entire site to finish loading before the next one opens on the separate browser window

Comment: if you want to open the urls in different tabs/windows then you have tcan replace the line in `getUrl` method with this line and see `driver.execute_script('window.open(arguments[0]);',x)`.

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to open the urls in different tabs/windows then you have tcan replace the line in getUrl method with this line and see

```
driver.execute_script('window.open(arguments[0]);',x)
```

Comment: Please accept the answer by clicking on the hallow check mark below the downvote button. Feel free to upvote the answer for the benefit of future readers.